# Determine if WorkSheet.Name is NOT in Workbook or String is not in Array VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, excel, vsto

This seems like such a simple question, but I can't seem to find a good way to do it.  I want to check if the name of an Excel Worksheet with an index of `'n'` is not in the original set of worksheet names of my VSTO workbook.

The workbook has 13 worksheets in the template and the program adds more sheets to the end and sometimes the middle. Any sheet added wouldn't be named one of the sheet names included in the template (I've successfully blocked this).  I often want to take actions to all the sheets added that are not of the orginal 13, so I had hoped to try and use an array, or the list ThisWorkbook.Names as it exists from the initial template.

Right now my work around is:

```
 If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(n).Name <> Sheet1.Name OrElse ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(n).Name <> wbX.Sheet2.Name ..... <>wbX.Sheet13.Name
```

Needless to say this is cumbersome.  Am I even thinking about this the right way, or is there an easier way to check if a name is not in the original sheet names?

I know that if I could force all the sheets after 13 I could just use the index, but at the moment that's not feasible for the intention of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At startup fill all worksheetnames from the template into a List:

```
Dim templateSheets As List(Of String) = new List(Of String)
For Each sheet As Excel.Worksheet in Globals.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
  templateSheets.Add(sheet.Name)
Next
```

Then your above query can get abbreviated to

```
If Not templateSheets.Contains(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(n).Name) Then
```

Comment: I'm actually not going to do it at startup, as that would then expand when they save and come back to it, but I hard coded a list once and stored it as data in the VSTO.  Thanks